# invalid-api-key in Watson Visual Recognition API

Tags: api-key, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I would like to classify images by calling Watson Visual Recognition APIs.

So, I set my end point as

```
(a) and sent a request message as 
(b) However, I received an error message as 
(c) How can I resolve this issue?
```

> FYI. - The API Key was generated on IBM Bluemix.

**(a) End Point :** "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify";

**(b) Captured Request Message**

```
reqMessage: {"api_key":"XXXX" ,"url":"http://cfile5.uf.tistory.com/image/1876DE4C4F29F9F13BB066",
"version":"2016-05-20", "classifirer_ids":default","owners":"IBM"}
```

**(c) Captured Response Message**

```
resMessage: {"status": "ERROR", "statusInfo": "invalid-api-key"}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Updated. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: Two things scream out at me, but neither will be the root cause of the invalid-api-key. 
First you have a typo in "classifirer_ids" which should be "classifier_ids". Second you have provided your key, which means that it is now compromised and if it is valid, you need to invalidate it.

Comment: How did you obtain the key? There are several things that could be going on here. 
1. The Key verification engine in the service is down.
2. You are trying to re-use an AlchemyAPI key, which won't work. 
3. You have allocated more than one key, and only one key is allowed per user per Bluemix region.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your request. I know that the Visual Recognition V3 API had some hiccups with the key management around the date you post this question so I think this was a server side error.

If you try it again it will work.